# JQuery button.click() handler fires without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Right now I'm doing some clean up code for my auction game, but my function is fired immediately after `endAuction()` is called rather than when the button is clicked. I can't seem to figure out why, and I'm not terribly familiar with JavaScript or jQuery, can anyone point out my issue?

```
endAuction:function()
{
    var i = 0;
    var btnID = "as" + (i).toString(),
        liID = "asli" + (i).toString();
    var cleanBtn = $('li#' + liID + ' button#' + btnID);
    cleanBtn.text("Sold!");

    var btn = $('#' + btnID);
    btn.off().click(this.cleanUpAuction());
},

cleanUpAuction:function()
{
    console.log("Removing button");
    userStats.money += currentBid;
    currentBid = 0;

    var i = 0;
    var liID = "asli" + (i).toString();
    var carElement = $('li#' + liID);

    carElement.remove();
},
```

Comment: because you are calling it, not assigning it!

Comment: Change `.click(this.cleanUpAuction())` to either `.click(this.cleanUpAuction)` or `.click(function(){this.cleanUpAuction()})`.

Comment: @j08691 And that one is going to be wrong since this is out of scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function, not assigning a reference to it.

Change

```
.click(this.cleanUpAuction())
```

to

```
.click(this.cleanUpAuction)
```

or

```
.click($.proxy(this.cleanUpAuction, this))
```

Comment: Well that certainly solves my issue of it auto-firing, but when I do that and press the button nothing happens now. What the function does is removes the element and gives the player their money for the auction, neither of which happens on click.

Comment: I had a copy paste error in the code... so is the method called? Add console.log into the function.

Comment: No it never gets called

Comment: I need more context to answer your question.

Comment: Edited OP with the function that is supposed to be called, hope that helps.

Comment: And you sure you are finding the button? `console.log(btn)`

Comment: The button id seems to match, both being `as0`

Comment: Okay so I seem to have found it. Interestingly enough the `cleanBtn` I had declared was actually what needed to have the function bound to it. You get the answer though seeing as you solved the major problem (auto-firing function)